# How does scrollTop() work

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I was trying out how i would scroll up or down a table and this snippet worked

```
$('.scroll-down').click(function() { 
    $('.tableholder').animate({ 
       scrollTop: $('.tableholder').scrollTop() + 10
    });
});
 $('.scroll-top').click(function() { 
    $('.tableholder').animate({ 
       scrollTop: $('.tableholder').scrollTop() - 10
    });
});
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/45gLR/3/

What explanation can be given to explain why scrollTop worked in this way?

Comment: What is the problem ?  however we have api docs  -- > http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: I think it is working properly see http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/45gLR/3/show/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clicked on the `scroll-down` button the value of `$('.tableholder').scrollTop()` was 0 and after event occurred it's value changed to 0 + 10 = 10;

Next, if you clicked on the `scroll-top` button the value of `$('.tableholder').scrollTop()` will be 10 this time and after event occurred it's value changed to 10 - 10 = 0;

And thats, how it goes down and up.

To make your code, bit faster and better, you can do this:

```
var $tableholder = $('.tableholder');
$('.scroll-down').click(function () {
    $tableholder.stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $tableholder.scrollTop() + 10
    });
});
$('.scroll-top').click(function () {
    $tableholder.stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $tableholder.scrollTop() - 10
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code literally explains itself. Did it do something you weren't expecting, or did you expect it to do something different? If so, elaborate so we can provide a better explanation.

`$('.tableholder').scrollTop() + 10` = get current scrollTop position, add 10px

`$('.tableholder').scrollTop() - 10` = get current scrollTop position, remove 10px

Then the animate function animates the `scrollTop` value to the new position, as determined by the above code.